# android: Play different sounds on each click

Tags: java, android, audio, soundpool

I have a button and on each click I want a different sound to play. I need some help getting the second sound to work. Here's my code so far:

```
package com.andrew.finnandjake;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Main extends Activity {
private SoundManager mSoundManager;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mSoundManager = new SoundManager();
    mSoundManager.initSounds(getBaseContext());
    mSoundManager.addSound(1, R.raw.finn_whatthejugisthat);
    mSoundManager.addSound(2, R.raw.finn_wordtoyourmother);


    Button SoundButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button1);
    SoundButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            mSoundManager.playSound(1);
            mSoundManager.playSound(2);


        }
    });
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create an iterator that increments each time the button is clicked, and then use if statements to determine which sound to play based on the value of the iterator.

Comment: Is there a way to create an iterator that will increment up to say 8 clicks, then reset back to 1? I'm really not sure how to go about doing that.

Comment: @aneal declare a integer, to hold the iteration variable, then on every click increment it, then use an if statement or something like that to check if the value is above a certain amount. If it is, then reset it to one. That's how I would implement it anyways